# A function like is_page() but returns true if on any sub page of given page

Tags: pages, conditional-content, recursive

In my header I use this code:

```
if(is_page("stores")) {
    // Do something
}
```

I run some code if on the page `stores` but what I want to do is run that code if the page is `stores` or any page that is a sub page of stores. Not only that, but is recursive so if we are on a sub sub sub page of `stores` the code still runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using pretty permalinks, I simply check against the request;

```
if ( preg_match( '#^stores(/.+)?$#', $wp->request ) ) {
    // away we go!
}
```

No extra DB queries, little computation, and works right down the tree!

Comment: I'm going to go for this as this will also work on my CPTs.

Comment: `$wp` needs to be defined as a global for this to work outside of the loop.

thusly `global $wp;` if you want to create a function in `functions.php`

Comment: @dgrebb To be clear `$wp` needs to be `global`'d inside functions and files outside of "normal" WP, but any template loaded in via the template system will already have the `$wp` variable available - in or outside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

[Testing for sub-Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#Testing_for_sub-Pages) section of Conditional Tags article in Codex has fitting code example that uses [`get_post_ancestors()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors) to retrieve parent tree and loops through it with check.

Answer (score 4):

Handy little function

```
 function is_child_of($parent) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->post_parent == $parent){
        return true
    }else{
        $curent_parent = $post->post_parent;
        $dec = false;
        while ($curent_parent > 0){
            $p = get_post($curent_parent);
            $curent_parent = $p->post_parent;
            if ($curent_parent > 0){
                if ($curent_parent == $parent){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    return false;
}
```

Usage:
check if current is a child of a page with the ID of 22

```
if (is_child_of(22)){
  //its a child of 22
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a great answer, because I don't think it answers the question very well. It's not recursive, and it's not a step-in equivalent of `is_page()` as you can only pass the page ID. `is_page()` supports ID, slug and name. 

I hope this doesn't sound obnoxious, just just disagree :s

Comment: @Joe my bad, i didn't read the whole question, anyway i updated the answer with an altered function which works but on page id only no names or slugs, which shouldn't be too hard to add, simply query the passed $parent if its not an integer using `pagename` parameter.